# SpriteKit physics: How to make a player sprite follow the (sloped) ground

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision, skphysicsbody

I am creating a tilemap platform game in SpriteKit. I assigned collision paths to the physics body of all ground tiles and made them non-dynamic. To the player I assigned two collision polygons: a circle on the bottom and a rectangle on the top.

The player sprite has a fixed position on screen, while the level is scrolling from right to left. Now, as long as the player sprite is on flat ground, the collisions work perfectly and the player is walking on the ground. However, I also have some sloped terrain tiles that I want the player to follow (e.g. walking uphill). But when the player reaches a sloped tile, he simply bounces off of it, being unable to "climb" it.

[image: screenshot]

Similarly, when I drop the player from above on a sloped tile, he slides down the "hill", instead of remaining in position.

I have both restitution and friction set to 0.

So how can I make the player sprite follow the ground regardless of its shape and how can I make the player stay on a sloped tile instead of sliding down?

I tried using SKConstraints with positionX set to a constant value. At first it seemed to work, but then the player got stuck in the middle of a sloped tile and eventually fell through it.

I also tried different shapes of collision polygons on the player (e.g. a rectangle instead of a circle at the bottom) but that changed nothing.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has more to do with your game logic instead of your map properties. You need to have several "states" for your player. For example, if your player is idle you can set the CGVector to 0,0. This will stop the player from moving in any direction.

To give you some examples on movement. Let's say you want to make your object move right:

```
// move node's physics body to the right while leaving vertical movement as is
// 160 is just an example
myNode.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(160, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy);

// do not allow right movement to exceed 160
if(myNode.physicsBody.velocity.dx > 160)
    myNode.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(160, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
```

To move left you inverse the dx value:

```
myNode.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(-160, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy);

if(myNode.physicsBody.velocity.dx < -160)
    myNode.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(-160, self.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
```

Allow myNode to be affected by gravity and it should remain in contact with the ground as it moves down a slope.

Comment: What CGVector do you mean? The velocity vector of the physics body? I was able to make the player follow the slopes by enabling / disabling its affectedByGravity property when he is on a down-slope / up-slope. However, the horizontal movement is kinda odd, as it slows down when he travels uphill and speeds up when he travels downhill instead of maintaining a constant speed.

Comment: Turns out that switching gravity on/off did not work so well. I'm starting to become really desperate. Is it by any chance possible for you to show some code snippets that help me understand how to handle player movement on slopes? There are so many factors here (e.g. gravity, friction, collisions, velocity, etc.) that I have the feeling I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @snorge - added movement examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing some code. I tried your solution and it works perfectly when the player moves down a slope. However, moving up a slope is still not working. As soon as the player sprite hits a slope it struggles really hard to get up that tile, meaning its horizontal movement is slowed way down. Referring to the original screenshot up top, the player manages to (slowly) ascend the first two slope tiles. But when reaching the third tile (45 degree angle) it cannot overcome it because it is too steep. Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: @snorge - There's a couple of properties in the physics body you can play with. Set the friction to 0.0 Next set the mass and density to a very low value. The less mass and the less dense your node is, the easier it will be to move. Less friction also makes it easier to move around.

Comment: Oh my god, it works! Thank you so much. Setting the density to a very low number did the trick. Awesome!

Comment: @snorge - Did you manage to get the desired result? If so I was wondering what friction / mass / density values you set? I am doing something very similar and I just can't get my sprite to climb the slope at all. It simply starts and then immediately slides back. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tilemap platform game...

Then gravity isn't important, put gravity to a very low value and then change all your impulses for the jumps and such in relation to the change in gravity...

OR,

Possibly, if the game isn't randomly generated you can set up a uibezierpath, and turn the path off if he stops moving up the hill.

But then if he stopped mid-hill or was starting from the top, he would still slide down...

And increasing friction (not setting it to 0) may help. Try friction at 1?